# Beamer multimedia is not working

Tags: beamer, adobe, multimedia

Using the `beamer` and `multimedia` packages I'm not able to reproduce videos from Adobe Acrobat Reader. For example, when I create a PDF with the next LaTeX code, which I copied from an example on the web that was supposed to work, I get the PDF but nothing reproduces.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{color}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title frame}

\movie[height = 0.6\textwidth, width = 0.8\textwidth, poster, showcontrols]{}{example.avi}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, if I substitute the name of the file for a non-existent one (e.g, `wrongname.avi`), then in the PDF it asks me to choose another file and then I can reproduce it. Anyone has any idea of what can be happening?

Thank you!

Comment: We don't have the movie...would you mind providing a way to have access to it?

Comment: The file is here @heather: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2cFb1QuGgdHM3dVNGw4bWY5bzg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: No problem here. The video is played in AR DC on windows.

Comment: I'm using sharelatex and there aren't any errors, but the movie doesn't show up...I am new using beamer so I could just be missing something.

Comment: Then download the ready PDF and put it in the same dir as the video file, open the pdf in AR and click on the video. It should play as it does for me.

Comment: Thanks for trying, it seems it works in your computers. This is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2cFb1QuGgdHMjU5VWxOU25rRVk/view?usp=sharing) of the pdf I generate. Does it work for you? And if someone can share his pdf so I can try it in my computer, that would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved using

`\usepackage{movie15}`

and

```
\includemovie[poster,mouse=true]{8cm}{6cm}{video.wmv}
```

and it worked with avi file also.

Anyway, it doesn't work fine on windows 10